# useQuery not returning up to date data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

- i have a homepage (`/home`) with a list of products as cards (retrieved
  via `useQuery`) each of which has an upvote button
- when I click upvote,
  i trigger a mutation to upvote +  a UI change to update the vote
  count
- when i go to another page, and then go back to `/home`,
  `useQuery` doesn’t retrieve the products with the correct vote count
- however, when I check my DB, the products all have the correct vote
  count.

Why does`useQuery` not return the right amount until i do another page
refresh?

for reference, here it is below:

```
const Home = props => {
  const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_LOGGED_IN, {
    variables: {
      userid: props.userid
    }
  });
  
  console.log(
    'data', data.products // this data is outdated after I go from /home -> /profile -> /home
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      {_.map(data.products, product => (
        <VoteButton
          hasVoted={product.hasVoted}
          likes={product.likes}
          productid={product.productid}
        />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

```
const VoteButton = ({likes, hasVoted, productid}) => {
  const [localHasVoted, updateLocalHasVoted] = useState(hasVoted);
  const [likesCount, updateLikesCount] = useState(likes);
  const [onVote] = useMutation(VOTE_PRODUCT);

  const onClickUpvote = (event) => {
    onVote({
      variables: {
        productid
      }
    })
    updateLocalHasVoted(!localHasVoted);
    updateLikesCount(localHasVoted ? likesCount - 1 : likesCount + 1);
  }
  
  return (
    <VoteContainer onClick={onClickUpvote}>
        <VoteCount >{likesCount}</VoteCount>
    </VoteContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: You're probably using cache in your apollo client, you need to update it manually, it is pretty annoying: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates

Comment: ah man i hate this

Comment: use 'network-only' policy if you don't want to 'fight' with ['annoying'] cache updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your useQuery call, you can actually pass it a config option called 'fetch-policy' which tells Apollo how you want the query to execute between making the call or using the cache. You can find more information here, [Apollo fetch policy options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#configuring-fetch-logic).
A quick solution would be be setting fetch-policy to cache and network like the the example below.

```
  const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS_LOGGED_IN, {
    variables: {
      userid: props.userid
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  });
```

You can also make it so that when your mutation happens, it will run your query again by setting the 'refetch-queries' option on useMutation like the code below.
This will cause your query to trigger right after the mutation happens.
You can read more about it here [Apollo mutation options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#options)

```
const [onVote] = useMutation(VOTE_PRODUCT, {
  refetchQueries: [ {query: GET_PRODUCTS_LOGGED_IN } ],
});
```

Comment: yeah i had ended up using `cache-and-network`, thanks for the response though